# Setting up Ram disk & NFS

Tags: nfs, disk-management

I’m new to Linux so please forgive my lack of knowledge.
What I’m trying to do is the following:

Create a 32GB ram disk and mount it as an NFS export and give everyone full access to it. This is what I have tried so far:

Ram Disk

```
mkdir –p /mnt/ramdisk
chmod –r 777 /mnt/ramdisk
mount –t tmpfs –o size=32G tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk/
```

NFS

```
mkdir -p /exports/ramdisk
chmod –r 777 /exports/ramdisk
mount –bind /mnt/ramdisk /exports/ramdisk
```

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Tbone

Answer (score 3):

See [setting up NFS how to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo)

You should have an entry in /etc/exports related to the folder you are exporting on NFS, something like:

```
/exports/ramdisk *(fsid=25,rw,sync)
```

Run

```
sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart
```

After updating /etc/exports.

On the computer which you are mounting this share in /etc/fstab

```
ip-of-nfs-server:/exports/ramdisk /exports/ramdisk nfs rw,bg
```

Change the second path to whichever local folder you have created as a mount point, then run

```
sudo mount -a
```

After editing /etc/fstab.

The ramdisk will disappear on logout or reboot.